# Rails 3 module capitalization

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, module, capitalization

I'm upgrading an old Rails 2 app to 3.2. Rspec is giving me this error:

```
expected /app/models/api/key.rb to define Api::Key
```

The actual file is:

```
module API
  class Key
```

So the capitalization is wrong according to Rails convention. I'd like to avoid project wide searching and trying to change everywhere the constant is referenced. Is there any way to tell Rails the module is in all capitals?

For reference, I did try to use the inflector:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.acronym "API"
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Is it a caps issue? You have "API" and the error says its expecting "Api". I'm not sure if that would matter or not but it seems like it would

Comment: Yes, that is the problem. I'm looking for a way to solve it without having to change everywhere it's referenced.